# Does $(this) refer to the item clicked when inside a click function?

Tags: jquery, this

I have a fiddle here with multiple galleries: http://jsfiddle.net/cmscss/uh0cq4o8/

I'd like the buttons (next, prev and zoom) to refer to the gallery whose button was actually clicked but am having a lot of trouble understanding the many answers/blogs etc about `this`.

I've been trying to move up the DOM from the actual button clicked to define the correct gallery by replacing this:

```
next = ($('.gallery-item.active').prev().length > 0) ?
```

With something like:

```
next = ($(this).closest('.gallery').find('.gallery-item.active').prev().length > 0) ?
```

Or using parents like:

```
next = ($(this).parents('.gallery').find('.gallery-item.active').prev().length > 0) ?
```

But I'm not entirely sure where `this` is supposed to go.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: See also this FAQ entry found in the Wiki: https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is actually a very common scoping issue in JavaScript. In this particular case, yes this refers to the Button control itself. I would also want to point out that you can actually set what this refers to when you call a function by using .bind
It will take some time to get use to it

Comment: Thanks guys. So in this context, I guess I'm having trouble working out where to put ```this``` and/or how to change parent elements of the item clicked - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/uh0cq4o8/1/

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title, YES.

If by "click function" you mean "click callback", the `this` is indeed the clicked element.